# Create as many as object as you want

Tags: java

why is my average method not working they way it should be
i got the adding new objects to work but now my average mark is not working properly

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Q4Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] markArr = new int[1];
    int[] creditArr = new int[1];

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Number of Student :");
    int numberOfStudent = scn.nextInt();


    ArrayList<Q4> myStudentList = new ArrayList<Q4>();


    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudent; i++) {

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Student " + (i + 1) + " Name  :");
        String stName = scn.next();

        System.out.print("Student ID :");
        int stID = scn.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Number of Units :");
        int stNumOfUnit = scn.nextInt();

        for (int x = 0; x < stNumOfUnit; x++) {

            markArr = new int[stNumOfUnit];

            System.out.print("Mark for Unit " + (x + 1) + " :");
            int mark = scn.nextInt();

            markArr[x] = mark;

        }

        for (int x = 0; x < stNumOfUnit; x++) {

            System.out.print("Credit for Unit " + (x + 1) + " :");
            int credit = scn.nextInt();

            creditArr = new int[stNumOfUnit];
            creditArr[x] = credit;

        }

        myStudentList.add(new Q4(stName, stID, stNumOfUnit, markArr, creditArr));
        myStudentList.get(i).averageMark(markArr);

        System.out.println(myStudentList.get(i).averageMark(markArr));

    }


}
```

}

my Student class (Q4) and i know it s not the best name for your class but i have my reasons thanks

```
 import java.io.Serializable;
  import java.util.*;

 public class Q4 implements Serializable {

private String studentName;
private int studentID;
private  int numberOFUnit;
private int[] mark;
private int[] credit;

public Q4(){

}

public Q4(String studentName,int studentID,int numberOFUnit,int[] mark,int[] credit){

    this.studentID = studentID;
    this.studentID = studentID;
    this.numberOFUnit = numberOFUnit;
    this.mark = mark;
    this.credit = credit;

}// end of constructor

public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}

public int getStudentID() {
    return studentID;
}

public int getNumberOFUnit() {
    return numberOFUnit;
}

public int[] getCredit() {
    return credit;
}

public int[] getMark() {
    return mark;
}

public void setStudentName(String studentName) {

    this.studentName = studentName;
}

public void setStudentID(int studentID) {
    this.studentID = studentID;
}

public void setNumberOFUnit(int numberOFUnit) {
    this.numberOFUnit = numberOFUnit;
}

public void setMark(int[] mark) {
    this.mark = mark;
}

public void setCredit(int[] credit) {
    this.credit = credit;
}

public double averageMark(int[] array){

    double sum = 0;

    for(int i=0 ; i < array.length ; i++){

        sum = sum + array[i];

    }

    return sum/array.length;
}
```

}// end of class

Comment: You've done it. What's the question?

Comment: Also, why do you name `Q4` a class that represents a student. Why not name it... `Student`?

Comment: @EJP i need to create a loop so the user can add the information

Comment: You should definitly name your class (which you are call Student in your post) from `Q4` to `Student`!

Comment: i am doing this question sheet and i d like to keep the record of my questions

Comment: Then name the *project* Q4, or the git or SVN *branch* Q4. Or even the package. But not the class.

Comment: CYBERSIX: have a look at: http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm 

Classes: Names should be in CamelCase. Try to use nouns because a class is normally representing something in the real world:
   `class Customer` or
   `class Account`

Comment: Take `average = sum / array.length;` out of the for lop, you only need to do this once when you know the total score.

Comment: So create a loop. What's the question?

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.print("Number of Student :");
int numberOfStudent = scn.nextInt();
ArrayList<Q4> myStudentList = new ArrayList<Q4>();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudent; i++) {
     myStudentList.add(new Q4()); 
}
```

Though you have already achieved what you stated in your question this will allow you to create the instances by making use of an arraylist and a for-loop.

Comment: how do i populate the mark and credit array now

Comment: Make a function to add something to the mark and credit array in your class. Next: myStudentList[0].yourFunctionToAdd(10);

Answer (score 2):

Check this to create the students you want

```
while(numberOfStudent>0){
   create each student
   numberOfStudent--;
}
```